# Write a bijection to match the set of positive integers with the set of positive integers excluding the multiples of 4.

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions, discrete-mathematics

Write a bijection to match the set of positive integers with the set of positive
integers excluding the multiples of 4.

e.g. $$1\mapsto1,2\mapsto2, 3\mapsto3, 4\mapsto 5, 5\mapsto , 6\mapsto 7, 7\mapsto9, \dots $$

I don't have any idea where to start the process of defining such a bijection. 
And is it possible to define more than one bijection for the particular question above?

Comment: Hey Kaan! Nice question! One note though, when posting questions to Math.SE, I'd like to invite you to consider including your thoughts/attempts on solving the problem, (even if you have your doubts).  

For example, you wrote that you don't have any idea on where to start on this problem-- an explanation as to why you feel/think you're stuck would be sufficient! It helps show question answerers goodwill and makes for high quality questions. We appreciate you joining our community and good luck in the future!

Answer (score 1):

For example you can try
$$f(n)=n + \lfloor (n-1)/3\rfloor.$$
Does it work? Are you able to find another bijection?

As a bonus question, find a bijection from the set of of positive integers with the set of positive integers excluding the multiples of a given integer $m>1$.

Comment: How did you find the bijection though? Is there a general process for defining a bijection for any given sets?

Comment: I don't think there is a general rule. Why don't you try to find another bijection? Take a bijection from the set of of positive integers onto itself different from the identity and...

Comment: The function works pretty well by the way, thanks.

Comment: It's just that everytime I see a question like this, all I can do is try to match the values in the domain with the ones in the codomain and define a function out of it randomly, thought maybe there is an algorithm that I can stick through but there is no such a thing appearently.

Comment: I did verify it, it works pretty well.

Comment: Try to find another bijection. Show some effort!!

Comment: Good day Robert!
From how things read, I don't think Kaan is asking you to do any verification.They are expressing their gratitude for the hint of the bijection. If you wouldn't mind considering how your repeated comments directing him to "show some effort" are unnecessary, (and read somewhat hostile to me), I would super appreciate it

Comment: Given one bijction is easier to find another one. But you have to try... I'm repeating myself...

Comment: Now might be a good time to step back from the answer and let the OP ponder how to proceed?

Comment: @Rustyn You are right. Let's wait...

Comment: I do understand where both are coming from and I appreciate the hint as much as I'm sure the OP does :) Thanks for your contribution